# How do we fulfill the positive commandment to be crazy?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

How do we fulfill the positive commandment in Devarim 28:34 which commands us to be crazy:

> וְהָיִיתָ, מְשֻׁגָּע

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: By having and raising children.

Comment: Fascinatingly, R. Yudelovitch insulted the Rogathchover as one who fulfills the mitsva to be crazy: ולכן הוא מבולבל ומשוגע ומקיים מ"ע והיית משוגע בכל פרטיה ודקדוקיה כראוי לצדיק

Answer (score 8):

By asking such questions on MiYodeya you fulfill this commandment L'Mhadrin min Hamihadrin.

Answer (score 5):

By looking in a mirror. As the full pasuk states, והיית משגע ממראה