# Is there a mitzvah to be crazy?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[Devarim 28:34](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9617&st=&pgnum=346&hilite=) says:

> והיית משגע
>
> You shall be crazy

Frequently, when one is unsure of the meaning of a word or phrase, we use the technique of גזירה שוה. This is a technique that looks for usage of the same word or phrase elsewhere. If the meaning is clear in another place, then we apply that same meaning in the verse we were studying.

So using the גזירה שוה technique, I found the use of והיית in [Devarim 16:15](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9617&st=&pgnum=220) where regarding Succot it says:

> והיית אך שמח
>
> You should be exceedingly happy

The rabbis learned that there is a specific mitzvah to be happy on Yom Tov. So, apparently, the term והיית implies a mitzvah.

Would it be fair to use the גזירה שוה technique to learn that it is also a mitzvah to be crazy at all times, or is the Torah referring to a specific occasion or circumstance when there might be a mitzvah? Or, perhaps, this is not a mitzvah but, just a suggestion?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: FYI that's not how a gezerah shaveh works.

Comment: @Daniel Maybe I'm using the wrong term. I know there is one technique that finds similarities from phrases.

Comment: @mevaqesh You may be thinking of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35925/5275. But that one assumes that it is a mitzvah. My question is not a dupe of that one.

Comment: They seem similar enough to be dupes. (Particularly since they share the same pun, which is really the main part of this Purim Torah question). The community can decide whether or not it is a dupe.

Comment: You've got the term right. It's just the mechanics of how it's applied that are wrong.